# I need to show a dialog when has no network available and dismiss it when network works back

Tags: java, android

I have a situation here...

I create a receiver in my app to receive network events; Easy peasy, everything is working good...

My problem starts here:
I need to show up a dialog when no network is available and auto dismiss it when network works back;

I tried to just show the dialog using onReceive method context param, but a invalid token error was threw;

I tried to use an Activity too by saving the it in a static variable, but another error shows up.

Anyone has a how to ideia?

Tks..

UPDATE-

Error in static Activity:

Unable to start receiver com.shelly.shellyapp.communication.NetworkChangeReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52800c40 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-688,486} not attached to window manager

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver is getting invoked even after activity is finishing / in the process of getting destroyed. Here you need to register the receiver in onResume() of the activity and de register in onStop of the activity.

Also, to restore the network popup state. Just check in onResume() if network is available if not display the popup else remove the popup.